# C# Remove "Ghost Straight Line" from Chart

Tags: c#, charts

how can I remove this Straight Line from left to right?

And why do I see this "Ghost" Line? I am not generating this Line :S

[image: Chart]

Or is my Code Broken?

```
            chart1.Series.Clear();

            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackColor = Color.Black;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.SlateGray;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.SlateGray;
            chart1.Legends[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            await Task.Delay(100);

            string seriesName1 = "Test";
            Series ser1 = chart1.Series.Add(seriesName1);
            ser1.ChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;
            ser1.Name = seriesName1;
            ser1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Stock;
            ser1.BorderWidth = 2;
            ser1.Color = Color.Red;

            for (int ix = 0; ix < feechValues.Count(); ix++)
            {
                ser1.Points.AddXY(feechValues[ix].CreateTime, feechValues[ix].Test);
            }
            for (int ixx = 0; ixx < feechValues.Count(); ixx++)
            {
                ser1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                ser1.Points[ixx].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond;
                ser1.Points[ixx].MarkerSize = 4;
                ser1.Points[ixx].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `feechValues` are always increasing in time? It looks like the last value has a time which is much earlier than a lot of the other values.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, every new Data from feechValues have a other Time (increasing)

Comment: Are you *certain* about that? Double-check it. It really looks like the final point has the second-smallest time.

Comment: @canton7 Oh wow.. I was Sure i dont have Double Data in feechValues, but i do... Thx for the hint, this was simple, thank you :)

Comment: @canton7 you should add that as an answer so it can be accepted.